Merging unallocated partition on a dynamic drive
So I have unallocated space on my drive, sandwiched between two recovery partitions of unknown provenance. I'm trying to merge it into my C: drive, but since they aren't adjacent I couldn't extend volume. Next, I (stupidly) converted the drive to a dynamic one (since the name seemed like it would allow me to move the partitions) but that only made it worse, since I can't even delete the recovery drives using override in CMD now.
Are there any ideas for how I can actually merge the unallocated space into the C: drive without formatting everything?
My disk manager:


Dynamic Disks are depreciated software RAID. To undo, all partitions must be deleted, then it can be converted back to a basic disk. Since all partitions have to be removed and recreated, Capture separate WIMs of the OS and both WinRE partitions (Step 1 at top of answer), then follow Steps 1 - 6 at bottom of answer (Apply the WIMs after Step 4)

1. Convert your dynamic disk back to a simple basic partition
Convert the partition type of your C-partition to from a dynamic disk type one to a basic NTFS one.
You can use TestDisk to do this.
Here are two sources for a detailed description of partition types:
https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTypes.htm
https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html
Shut down your machine and restart.
Your dynamic disk partition should have become a basic one.
If that fails because you are currently running windows from Disk0 run Windows or linux on a different machine and connect your disk in question as an additional one using an USB adaptor.
2. Move your recovery partition the right
Use a partitioning tool to move your recovery partition with a size of 1,17 GB to the right as far as you can do. This will make the free space appear of 92,74 GB between the partition that is labeled "C" and the recovery partition with a size of 1,17 GB.
3. Enlarge your "c"-partition
Extend your partition that is labeled "C" into the free space to the right. As far as I know the more recent versions of Windows support enlarging partitions to the right hand side.

I can't seem to figure out how to convert the C-partition to a basic NTFS one in TestDisk? There's almost a hundred options for disk type to convert to, is there a preferred one to use?

@JoepvanSteen Has it been verified that will result without data issues, as I'm assuming Microsoft explicitly states the only way to undo this is to delete all partitions and convert the drive back to a Basic type?
